# drawing graph (0 and 1)

Tags: matlab, graph, drawing, bipartite

I have one matrix and i drew a bipartite graph Like below in MATLAB .

```
F =

     1     0
     2     1
     3     0
     4     0
     5     1
     6     0

plot(F','-*','Color','b','LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','r')

axis([0, 3, -2, size(F, 1) + 1])
```

In this case all line are connected *(0 and 1)* of 2nd column separately.
But I want to connect only if the element of 2nd column is equal to **1.**
No need for 0.
How can I draw or how can I write code in MATLAB?

[image]

Comment: Post your code so that we can suggest modifications on it

Comment: Here: 
plot(F','-*','Color','b','LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','r')
 axis([0, 3, -2, size(F, 1) + 1])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change:

```
plot(F','-*','Color','b','LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','r')
```

... to:

```
plot(F(F(:,2) == 1,:)','-*','Color','b','LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','r')
```

By changing `F` to `F(F(:,2) == 1,:)` you're telling Matlab to use only the rows of `F` where the second column equals to 1.

Comment: Woo! gr8! I got it.
Thanks.